# Conditional replace function in excel power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am just wondering if there is a way I can use replace function conditionally to achieve this---if column A is "aa" then replace the 23 in column B with 10 from Column C

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 23 | 10 |
| das | 44 | 51 |
| fdd | 21 | 30 |

and the output should be something like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 10 | 10 |
| das | 44 | 51 |
| fdd | 21 | 30 |

Please help

Any ideas will help

Comment: Ok, we helped. Did this answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Replace=  Table.ReplaceValue(Source,  each [b], each if [a]="aa" then [c] else [b] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"b"})
in  Replace
```

[image]

Capitalization of column names matters, so use A in place of a if you need